# How to consume 100 messages without ack, then do work and then acknowledge them?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I'm consuming messages from a rabbitmq with spring amqp. 
I'm consuming one message at a time and its pretty slow cause I save it to DB. So opening and closing transactions every time.

Right now I've set up a consumer like this.

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "queuename")
public void receive(Message message) {
 someservice.saveToDb(message);
}
```

But this is really slow. I would like to consume a bunch of messages before I start saving them. Then I can open a transaction. Save 300 and then commit and load the next batch.

Would something like this work?

```
class MessageChannelTag {
  Message message;
  Channel channel;
  long tag;
}

@Component
class ConsumerClass {

 List<MessageChannelTag> messagesToSave = new ArrayList<>();

 @RabbitListener(queues = "queuename")
 public void receive(Message message, Channel channel,  @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag)
            throws IOException {
    messagesToSave.add(new MessageChannelTag(message, channel, tag));
 }

 @Scheduled(fixedDelay=500)
 public void saveMessagesToDb() {
    List saveTheese = new ArrayList(messagesToSave);
    messagesToSave.clear();
    service.saveMessages(saveTheese);
    for(MessageChannelTag messageChannelTag:messagesToSave) {
    //In the service I could mark the rows if save succeded or not and
    //then out here I could ack or nack.. 

 messageChannelTag.getChannel().basicAck(messageChannelTag.getTag(), false);
    }
 }
}
```

Or if there is a simpler solution let me know. I prefer fast, simple and robust =)

Answer (score 1):

It might also be worth investigating if an "upstream" producer can provide batches of messages instead of individual ones.

Comment: There are two errors with this answer. First, the pull API (`basic.get`) is inefficient since it depends on client-side polling. Second, the "push API" (`basic.consume`) does not send messages one at a time unless configured to do so via the prefetch setting.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the "pull" API (`basic.get`), it is not nearly as efficient as consuming messages.

Set prefetch (also known as QoS) to 300, then acknowledge the messages at once when you are done. I am not familiar with Spring but I'm certain there are decorators or other ways to accomplish this.

This is all covered in the docs and tutorials - https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html

Comment: I changed the prefetch to 200. Then in my consumer I did like this.

`
@RabbitListener(queues = "QUEUENAME")
    public void recieve(Message message, Channel channel) throws IOException {
   //Here I add the messages to a list and once there is enough in the list I save them.
//Afterwards I manually acknowledge them.
//In spring boot. When you add Channel to the rabbitListener method then it will expect you manually acknowlegde the messages.
} `

One thing which would be great would be if I could ask if there was anything more prefetched. Like a way to ask if there will come more.

Comment: From my property.yml
`spring:
  rabbitmq:
    listener:
      direct:
        prefetch: 200
      simple:
        prefetch: 200
        acknowledgeMode: MANUAL`